# The type HTable(config,tablename) is deprecated. What use instead?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, deprecated

What can I use instead of `HTable(config,tablename)`?

This method is deprecated. In every example I could find they use this or another Constuctor, which is also deprecated.

Comment: Did you mean HTable(config, tablename) deprecated, didn't you?

Comment: OH!!! yea i meant HTable(config, tablename).. i will edit it!

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Constructing **`HTable`** objects manually has been **deprecated**. Please use **`Connection`** to instantiate a **`Table`** instead.

From a **Connection**, Table implementations are retrieved with [Connection.getTable(TableName)](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Connection.html#getTable%28org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName%29)

**Example:**

```
Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);

Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("table1"));

try 
{
   // Use the table as needed, for a single operation and a single thread
} 
finally
{
   table.close();
   connection.close();
}
```

Comment: when this table is used in a Pig in which  a Tuple is passed to the eval function of the UDF do i need to create and close connection for every tuple this would really impact performance is there any other way to do it

Comment: You can do multiple operations on the table before closing it.  Same goes for the connection.

Comment: is there a way for keeping it persistent connection as the older version used to provide ? @UserszrKs

Answer (score 2):

`Connection.getTable(TableName)` is used only for retrieving Table.

**If you need to create a table instead**, use `TableDescriptorBuilder` and `Admin.createTable(TableDescriptor)`.

For instance:

```
val tableDescriptor: TableDescriptor = TableDescriptorBuilder
                          .newBuilder(TableName.valueOf("mytable"))
                          .setColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyDescriptorBuilder.newBuilder("myId".getBytes).build())
                          .setColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyDescriptorBuilder.newBuilder("data".getBytes).build())
                          .build()

admin.createTable(tableDescriptor)
```

Answer (score 0):

HTable is no longer a client API. Use Table instead. here is the description in the api doc [here](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html):

> HTable is no longer a client API. Use Table instead. It is marked InterfaceAudience.Private as of hbase-1.0.0 indicating that this is an HBase-internal class as defined in Hadoop Interface Classification. There are no guarantees for backwards source / binary compatibility and methods or the class can change or go away without deprecation.